# How to run docker on port 8080 without docker -p option , but from dockerfile or dockercompose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i know when we give the -p option with docker run command like **docker run -p 8080:8080 *dockerimage*** , it will run on docker port 8080... but i want to write the docker run command with just container ID without -p option... like docker run imagename (without specifying port name)

if i write **EXPOSE 8080/tcp** in dockerFile , then when i run docker , it just opens port Exposed in dockerfile, but i want to make the docker run on specific port (not port 80) . May be docker-compose will help me achieve it ?

Please guide.

Comment: You can't, any more than you can cause `ls` to write to a file without adding a shell redirect.  The operator needs to tell Docker what ports to publish where; the image can't force specific host behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly no way to forward ports with Dockerfile but it is possible with `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  myapp:
    image: hello-world
    ports:
    - 8080:80
```

See the [compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Comment: Instead of ports 8080:80 , how can we make it work with 8080:82. Is this possible ?

Comment: @Onv the left value is the port on host, the right is the port in the container. You can use any two to create a forwarding rule. 8080:82 is also possible.

Comment: Using VS2019, i created an ASPNet Webforms application with container orchestration support using Docker-Compose.  In my Docker-Compose, i give the value of Ports 8080:80 , it works , but when i give 8080:81, it fails to launch (even thought in Docker File i say EXPOSE 81) . i tried with and without the EXPOSE statements in DockerFile, but no success

Comment: @Onv EXPOSE in Dockerfile does nothing. It's like a hint for your image users to know on which port your application is listening. Are you sure your application is listening on 81?